# How is Synergy Bonus determined?

Tags: splatoon-3

When I win a Splatfest Battle the amount of Clout and Splatfest Points I earn get a Synergy Bonus. Usually the bonus is x1.0 but sometimes it's x1.1 or x1.2. What determines the Synergy Bonus?

[image: Synergy Bonus 1.2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the combined look/style of all four teammates meets certain conditions, a **Synergy Bonus** is triggered. This bonus can multiply (between 1.1 and 2.0 times) the amount of Clout received when you win. Teams that meet these conditions are awarded a special team name, which is displayed at the start of a battle. These conditions are usually triggered when all four teammates share certain criteria:

- Headgear: Name, Brand and Type (caps, helmet, etc.)
- Shoes: Name, Brand and Type (boots, slip-ons, etc.)
- Species
- Hairstyle
- Weapons, Special, Sub Weapons, Types...

Source, [IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/splatoon-3/Splatfest_Guide).

Comment: For a second i was about to ask How about shirts, why are they not in the list? And then I realised I was dumb.

Comment: @Fredy31 Oh right, you can't change shirts during a Splatfest.

Comment: @Stevoisiak took you a second too hunh?